# Hibernate + PostgreSQL: Null boolean value being returned as 'true'

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, boolean

we're running into a strange bug on Hibernate + PostgreSQL:

We have an Hibernate 3.6 application that was previously tested on Firebird, MySQL and Derby, and now we are trying to get it to work on PosgreSQL 9.2; we're running into various weird problems that didn't happen in the previous databases, among those, there's a bug where nullable boolean fields that have *null* values in the database are loaded by Hibernate as *true*, instead of *null*. The corresponding properties on the persistent classes are all *java.lang.Boolean*, with no additional anotations.

Any ideas on what could cause this behaviour?

--- edit ---

Finally got time to do a more complete debugging: it turned out to not be an Hibernate error at all, but instead there was a LoadEventListener buried in a corner of our codebase. :P

Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I would look for Postgres-specific code in Hibernate, or if you have a Postgres-specific jar getting in the way. (For example, do you have the latest jdbc driver first in the classpath?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got time to do a more complete debugging: it turned out to not be an Hibernate error at all, but instead there was a LoadEventListener buried in a corner of our codebase. :P

Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure this is not a bug testing other PostgreSQL version.

Did you tried with PostgreSQL 9.1? 9.2 it's pretty new. 9.1 it's more stable.

Hibernate and other's persistence framework throws a few bugs when a new SGBD version is released.

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that as PostgreSQL can store null values as "unknown" that that value is somehow being mapped to "true" when it translates back to java.lang.Boolean.

Total wild guess though.